# DD4T: Access Root structure group metadata from child pages

Tags: 2013, dd4t, metadata

We're using DD4T in our project. There's a new request from our client to add something specific in the head/footer tags for one site.

I've tried adding it in a specific page metadata (two text fields) but I'm hesitant to leave the responsibility of displaying what we want to add on a page through content editors adding metadata in every page template.

Is there a way to retrieve a metadata value set within the Root structure group of the a publication when rendering any page underneath the root? Either through direct reference or recursively navigate back to the root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dd4t has some functionality in the tbbs to merge page metadata with metadata from parent items (structuregroups).
In the templates, you can add a tbb called ad inherited metadata to page, and set a parameter called mergeaction.

If you want to see what it does, you can see the code here
https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Templates/InheritMetadataPage.cs?r=65